# Windows 7 Desktop Screensaver (bubbles) going very fast

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

I have a W7 PC and when the bubbles screensaver starts, the bubbles fly all over the screen at a dizzy rate instead of neatly sliding and bouncing round.  Any ideas a) why and b) how to sort it?

Comment: Which behavior were you think of?  I'm nut sure that Windows allows any adjustment to the bubbles screensaver?

Comment: @Ramhound if you click settings, a message pops up saying: This screen saver has no options that you can set.

Comment: Yes, its say "This screen saver has no options that you can set"

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with this screensaver. Aparently the faster your computer is, the faster these bubbles will move. I compared the bubbles from a windows 7 in a VM and the native one on my desktop, and the speed changes are dramatically. In the VM it is slightly slower than I expect, but on my Windows 7 host, its pretty fast. Not dizzling fast, but definitely faster than a soothing set of bubbles.

This also happens with the other screensavers that do not have any settings.

EDIT: It seems you can edit these screensavers through the registry, and there's a program from sysinternals that allow you to edit the settings using a nice interface. See here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15088/customize-the-default-screensavers-in-windows-7-and-vista/

Comment: Judging by the speed these one go, you'd think it was a super computer (which its not).... They are really really fast, quite out of control

Comment: My computer is 6 years old (still able to play most games) but they move pretty fast here too.

Comment: also: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15088/customize-the-default-screensavers-in-windows-7-and-vista/

Comment: It's not related to computer speed cause they start to moveVERY fast after some time.

Comment: @Nikolai that doesn't happen on my end. They start moving pretty fast from the start already. But then again, I never have used this screensaver, so perhaps it will indeed go even faster after a while, which would still mean this is a problem with the screensaver.

Comment: @LPChip thanks for the link: [link] (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15088/customize-the-default-screensavers-in-windows-7-and-vista/) - that's really interesting (good ol' HTG)

Comment: @Nikolai - sounds like you have the same issue.  HTG article is a workaround, but we need a _solution_ ...

Comment: @gav Yes I do. but its not bothering me at all.