# Crazy Screen Saver (Bubbles screen saver became super fast)

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

I have Windows 7 with the generic Bubbles screen saver which usually works fine.

However, several times in the last couple of months I got back after a while being afk to see it went insane, and the bubbles were going at crazy speed.

Today I took a short video of this: (converted to gif)

[image]

After touching the mouse Windows resumed as if nothing has happened. Memory and CPU usage were all normal. Nothing was stuck, frozen, or out of the ordinary.

What can  cause this weird behavior of the screen saver?

Unlike the case in [Windows 7 Desktop Screensaver (bubbles) going very fast](https://superuser.com/questions/907073/windows-7-desktop-screensaver-bubbles-going-very-fast?rq=1), in my case this is not consitent, and happens only once in a while, still can't see any pattern or a way to reproduce. I did not change any hardware.

Comment: Hahaha, it looks like the screensaver's framerate isn't being capped to the screen refresh rate. What graphics card do you use, and have you changed any Vsync settings in the relevant graphics settings program?

Comment: @Sonickyle27 NVidia GeForce 8400 GS, now updating the driver based on other comment suggesting this. No idea what is "Vsync settings" so no, didn't change anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reinitialize the Bubbles screen-saver, try this :

1. Launch `regedit`
2. Navigate to
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Screensavers\Bubbles`
3. Open `Bubbles`
4. You will see two sub-keys : `Screen 1` and `Screen 2`
5. If the key `Bubbles` and its sub-keys contain any data besides
   `(Default)`, delete this data

If you wish to conserve the above data before deleting it,
right-click the `Bubbles` key and choose Export.

I note that users were having this same problem since the early days of
Windows, so it may be a very old bug that was never fixed by Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks, but both Screen 1 and Screen 2 have only Default entry, with "value not set" data.

Comment: Are your graphical drivers up-to-date from the manufacturer's website?

Comment: Good catch! Driver date is 03/02/2015 going to update now. Hopefully this will  eliminate that weird bug once and for all.

Comment: Driver updated, if the crazy bubbles won't come back until the bounty expires, it's yours. Thanks again!

Comment: Did the crazy bubbles come back ?

Comment: It came back for a while, and was gone for good after some update, forgot which. So it was something with Windows itself, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

set 'system clock resolution' to normal (15.600 ms)
Find out the current Windows timer frequency using the 'clockres' utility from sysinternals.